# Understanding of function pointer syntax in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

I have two questions

1. Are both of these declarations of setEvalFunction equivalent
   for `using EvalFunctionPtr = T (*)(const std::vector<T>&);`?

   ```
   a) void setEvalFunction(const EvalFunctionPtr& evalFunc);

   b) void setEvalFunction(T (* const &evalFunc)(const std::vector<T>&));
   ```
2. What is the difference between the following parameters (since both seem to work fine).

   ```
   a) T (* const &evalFunc)(const std::vector<T>&)

   b) T (* const &evalFunc)(const std::vector<T>&)&
   ```

I want to have something equivalent to 1 a), i.e. passing a reference to a constant function pointer, but without using some extra definition like `using EvalFunctionPtr = ...`.

Comment: Why not using `std::function`?

Comment: I don't think you need to bother with the reference at all. It's `const` so you can't change it and the cost of passing a function pointer should be the same as passing a reference to a function pointer.

Comment: I do not use std:function, because it is slower. Passing the value of a function pointer is passing a 64bit integer (in my case of a 64 bit system), which is not the same as passing the reference of a function pointer, since the reference is applied by the compiler, and takes zero time during runtime. But the copy of an integer takes time, doesn't it?

Comment: @xamid passing a reference doesn't take zero time during runtime. In fact, passing a reference argument to a function is practically copying the (probably 64 bit in your case) address of the pointer *and* dereferencing it (assuming you actually access the reference), which is more than just copying in the case of passing the pointer by value. If the function was expanded inline by the optimizer, then there is probably no difference either way.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Are both of these declarations of `setEvalFunction` equivalent

Yes.

> 2. What is the difference between the following parameters (since both seem to work fine).

I do believe that 2. b) `R (* const & fptr)(/*args*/)&` is ill-formed because a (non-member) function pointer cannot have a ref-qualifier, which is what the final `&` denotes. However, possibly due to a compiler bug, my GCC does accept it and parses it as same as `R (* const & fptr)(/*args*/)`. EDIT: clang correctly refuses to compile it.

> I want to have something equivalent to 1 a), i.e. passing a reference to a constant function pointer, but without using some extra definition like using `EvalFunctionPtr = ....`

That is quite apt description of 1. b).

> Passing the value of a function pointer is passing a 64bit integer (in my case of a 64 bit system), which is not the same as passing the reference of a function pointer, since the reference is applied by the compiler, and takes zero time during runtime. But the copy of an integer takes time, doesn't it?

Passing a reference doesn't take zero time during runtime. In fact, passing a reference argument to a function is practically copying the (probably 64 bit in your case) address of the pointer and dereferencing it (assuming you actually access the reference), which is more than just copying in the case of passing the pointer by value. If the function was expanded inline by the optimizer, then there is probably no difference either way.

Comment: When creating performance tests I get different results. e.g. doing a for loop 10 times, each time doing 10000000 times referencing, copying, and nothing but the for loop (over volatile int), then summing up the timespans gotten by using chrono::steady_clock::now(), i get for example: `Overall: 205425 μs taken for reference applies.
Overall: 220498 μs taken for copy applies.
Overall: 198125 μs taken for for-loop.
Overall: 196480 μs taken for reference applies.
Overall: 220580 μs taken for copy applies.
Overall: 197941 μs taken for for-loop.`
How can there be such a difference?

Comment: I was told about the zero-time performance of references by an assistant at university, who advises the c++ implementation part of my master thesis. I thought I could just trust him, and according to my tests it appears like he was right. However, I do not really find an article stating that.. I case you want my test, you can find it [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4954653/RWTH/cpp/refPerformanceTest.txt).

Comment: `R (* const & fptr)(/*args*/)&` is ill-formed, but it isn't attempting to declare a reference to reference. The second `&` is a ref-qualifier.

Comment: @xamid there are a few caveats in your test. 1. You've practically "inline expanded" the imagined function calls explicitly. So, this benchmark is not good for non-inlined functions. If you're only interested in inlined functions, then fair enough. 2. `volatile` copies cannot be optimized away, unlike non-`volatile` would be. 3. You don't use the result of the benchmark, so the optimizer can throw the entire loop away - except in the case of `volatile` copy - which cannot be optimized.

Comment: @xamid to slightly fix my previous comment: the entire loop cannot be thrown away because of volatile loop increment, but the unused reference initialization can be. All that you can get out of this benchmark is that references that are both **unused** and **inlined** are free :)

Comment: @user2079303 I have no optimization enabled, therefore these concerns are irrelevant. Why would it get any different results, if I stored the references (vs pointers) somewhere, to use it later? They clearly once existed. [Here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#reseating-refs) is written, that the address of a reference is the address of the referent, i.e. a reference is not stored anywhere in the memory. Therefore, to apply a reference, it has to be linked by the compiler directly, which is not during runtime. Do you have any sources that claim something different?

Comment: @xamid all of my arguments are based on optimization being enabled. Hardly anyone care more about non-optimized performance more than optimized, and benchmarking without optimization doesn't give any insight into the performance of an optimized build. You'd get different results if you stored the reference somewhere and used it later, because assigning an unused reference has no observable effects, so it can be implemented as a no-op according to the [as-if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) rule.

Comment: @xamid You've misintepreted the article. It doesn't say that address of a reference is the address of the referent. It says that when you *take* the address of a reference, you get the address of the referent. Reference not being stored anywhere in memory does not follow from that. A good source on the matter is the standard. It says: "It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage". In practice, this means that when the implementation of the reference needs storage, it will be provided storage.

Comment: @xamid the standard doesn't specify *when* a reference needs storage, but consider this: When a function (with external linkage) with a reference argument is compiled, the compiler cannot possibly know if the function will be called from other translation units. And it cannot possibly know where the referent objects will be. The references cannot be resolved at compile time. The address must be passed to the function and be dereferenced at runtime. It is common sense that a reference argument must use storage.